I am following a YouTube tutorial on making a weather app in swift but I have 2 errors which are preventing me from finishing the app
The Youtube tutorial I am following is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArfT4qOerL8
on lines 23 and 64 of my code for the ContentView section I have the error:
23: Value of type 'WeatherData has no member 'locationName'
64: Value of type 'Weather' has no member 'description'
Despite following the code exactly how it is in the video from what I can see, I am getting these errors, whereas in the video the person does not.
Here is a copy of my code from Xcode:
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  TheWeatherAppSimple
//
//  Created by Student02 on 09/05/2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State private var weatherData: WeatherData?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let weatherData = weatherData {
                Text("\(Int(weatherData.temperature))°C")
                    .font(.custom("", size: 70))
                    .padding()
                
                VStack {
                    Text("\(weatherData.locationName)")
                        .font(.title2).bold()
                    Text("\(weatherData.condition)")
                        .font(.body).bold()
                        .foregroundColour(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("CodeLab")
                    .bold()
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColour(.gray)
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .onAppear {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
        .onReceive(locationManager.$location) { location in
            guard let location = location else { return }
            fetchWeatherData(for: location)
        }
    }
    
    private func fetchWeatherData(for location: CLLocation) {
        let apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        let urlString =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(location.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(location.coordinate.longitude)&units=metric&appid=\(apiKey)"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let weatherResponse = try decoder.decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    weatherData = WeatherData(LocationName: weatherResponse.name, 
                                              temperature: weatherResponse.main.temp,
                                              condition: weatherResponse.weather.first?.description ?? "")
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

So far I've run the code through ChatGPT to check for any spelling errors which there were not. Any other code it gave me brought up more errors. I have very basic knowledge of Swift so I'm not really sure what else I could do myself to try and fix.

First show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code
and the full error messages you get.
Look carefully at what you have, you declare weatherData = WeatherData(LocationName: ...)
but you are trying to get Text("\(weatherData.locationName)"), note the lowercase.
Athough you don't show the code for Weather the property description has
probably been renamed because it is a Swift reserved word.
Most importantly, remove your secret API key from your post.

I edited the post to remove the key. But @Owen you should consider that API key compromised, void it out, and generate a new one. It's still visible in the edit history.

Note, for your code to work you need to add
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {...}.resume()

What is Weather, what is WeatherData? The declaration of those two types are the code you need to verify, both against what is in the video and against the json you download in the app.

The compiler is telling you what the errors are:
Value of type 'WeatherData has no member 'locationName'
Value of type 'Weather' has no member 'description'

Modify the definitions of those two structs/classes to include the fields you're referencing.

Thanks. I had a closer look at the specific bits and I managed to fix it after reading your help. Also don't worry about the API key, I just put a fake one in
